# How to force a variable to be treated as a String in perl?

Tags: json, string, perl, exponent

I have a JSON object which has a key value pair and the value of a one such pair is *0E10*.

The problem is that this value should be a string but this is being treated as a float because of the presence of letter *E* after a number, hence it is showing 0 whenever I print this value (0*e+10).

Can somebody please help me solve this problem?

I am using perl to pass the JSON and reading it through Javascript. (*Solution in any language would be acceptable*)

This is what I get when I print the JSON.

KEY1 : 0E10

KEY2 : "XYZ"

You can clearly see that, if the value is string it puts under quotes (") but for 0E10 it is not using the quotes (").

*The problem in my case is that I am reading the JSON from an API whose control is beyond my reach. I have a backend service which is written in perl which passes the JSON returned by the API. So whenever I hit a URL, the backend service written in perl is called. This service gets the JSON from the API and return back the JSON to the service which is hitting the URL.*

Comment: could you paste such json and how is being decoded?

Comment: you have `0E10` and not `"0E10"`, so it doesn't behave like string

Comment: You need to show people how you are creating the JSON.  Meanwhile perhaps the discussion in`perldoc` [`perlnumber`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html) will help.

Comment: JSON puts the string into quotes automatically, but in this case it is not doing so, because it is treating it as a float.

Comment: Are you saying the foreign API treats `key: 0E10` differently than `key: 0`, and that you want the former?

Comment: yes.. the foreign API treats key: 0E10 differently than key: 0, and that you want the former

Comment: why not try like this `$KEY1.""` before returning back the JSON. `.` would make it a string.

Comment: @Drt, he doesn't want a string. He wants to generate the following JSON: `key: 0E10`. Not `key: 0`, not `key: '0E10'`.

Answer (score 3):

See the difference:

**Option A**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $value = 12345;
my $hr = { KEY1=> $value, KEY2=> "XYZ" };
my $json = encode_json $hr;
print $json, "\n";
#<-- prints: {"KEY2":"XYZ","KEY1":12345}
```

**Option B**: double quote the $value assign to KEY1

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $value = 12345;
my $hr = { KEY1=> "$value", KEY2=> "XYZ" };
my $json = encode_json $hr;
print $json, "\n";
#<-- prints: {"KEY2":"XYZ","KEY1":"12345"}
```

Comment: But when I give $value as 0E10 it prints as 0. 
The problem in my case is that I am reading the JSON from an API whose control is beyond my reach. I have a backend service which is written in perl which passes the JSON returned by the API. So whenever I hit a URL, the backend service written in perl is called. This service gets the JSON from the API and return back the JSON to the service which is hitting the URL  

my $value = 0E10;
my $hr = { KEY1=> "$value", KEY2=> "XYZ" };
my $json = encode_json $hr;
print $json, "\n";

#<-- prints: {"KEY1":"0","KEY2":"XYZ"}

Comment: The string information is already lost when you say `my $value = 0E10`. You need to say `my $value = "0E10"`.

Comment: 0E10 has no sense in numeric context, because this is 0*10**10 = 0... perhaps the number you need is 1E10 ¿?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate `key: 0E10` (as opposed to `key: 0` and `key: '0E10'`), then you'll have to generate your own JSON. Perl doesn't have a way of storing `0E10` differently than `0E9`. (Neither do JavaScript, Java, C, C++, ...)

If you're willing to accept any exponent, you'll probably still have to generate your own JSON. Perl doesn't have a type system, and JSON encoders tend to use integer notation for integers (in the mathematical sense).

I specifically tested JSON::XS and JSON::PP will use `0` for a zero internally stored as a floating point number.

```
$ perl -MJSON::XS -MDevel::Peek -E'($_=1.1)-=$_; Dump $_; say encode_json([$_]);'
SV = PVNV(0x8002b7d8) at 0x800720f0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (NOK,pNOK)
  IV = 1
  NV = 0
  PV = 0
[0]

$ perl -MJSON::PP -MDevel::Peek -E'($_=1.1)-=$_; Dump $_; say encode_json([$_]);'
SV = PVNV(0x801602b0) at 0x8008e520
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (NOK,pNOK)
  IV = 1
  NV = 0
  PV = 0
[0]
```

(`NOK` indicates the scalar contains a value stored as a floating point number.)